# Adding .htaccess expires rules through PHP in a WordPress Plugin?

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

I am attempting to create my first WordPress plugin, based on a .htaccess idea of mine. I don't know PHP too, too well, but I can change around code and stuff.

How can I add .htaccess rules to .htaccess using PHP for WordPress?

For example, how would I use PHP to generate the following .htaccess code?:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess is simply a text file, so you can write/ read/ remove content from it using PHP functions responsible for this. Maybe `fopen` and `fwrite` can make you do this with extra coding and management of file permissions.

Second:
rewriting rules in .htaccess are concerning server configuration, I dont think there are functions in PHP responsible for configuring server behaviour. I am still looking for this and will give a feedback here.

**Edit:**

Look at these:

[Edit .htaccess with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899805/edit-htaccess-with-php)  **Jason Brumwell answer**

[Is PHP allowed to modify .htaccess file in current folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566950/is-php-allowed-to-modify-htaccess-file-in-current-folder)

http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/editing-htaccess-with-php-552406.html

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, if you could some how show me how through example code, I'd appreciate it. It would be of great help to me.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is definitely helpful and useful to me.

Comment: Not at all, I hope you achieve the plugin and make it available on the web. Good luck