# How to pass a value in URL with slash / in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, url, netsuite

i have to make a request where i have to pass an id in URL, but the id contains "/"

Ex: [http://www.example.com/products/{idProduct}](http://www.example.com/products/%7BidProduct%7D)

And i have this id "PU_597724/88_L_1" that in the middle contains "/"

http://www.example.com/products/PU_597724/88_L_1 -> the slash produces an 404 error.

Anyone knows how to pass this id without the URL taking the slash as another path in javascript?

Comment: .htaccess is what u looking for.
Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566950/is-php-allowed-to-modify-htaccess-file-in-current-folder)

Comment: IMHO, you only need to escape the slashes as %2F, or using encodeURIComponent (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: The ID would usually be a numeric or internal ID when used in such a URL schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slash (/) is a reserved character in RFC 3986 (specification for URL syntax).
But you can URL encode them.

- / is encoded as %2F
- _ is encoded as %5F

So in your request, substitute / and _ with encoded format